# How to convert from [Any] to [String: Any]

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code

```
 func performCallToEndpoint(_ endpoint:String, using method:String, body: [String:String]?, completion: @escaping (_ error:Error?, _ serverError: Error?, _ response: [Any]?) -> Void) {
        
        
        let request = createURLRequest(toEndpoint: endpoint, using:method, body: body)
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error: error calling POST")
                completion(nil, error, nil)
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                print("Error: Did not receive data")
                return
            }
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200 ..< 299) ~= response.statusCode else {
                print("Error: HTTP request failed")
                return
            }
            do {
                guard let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [Any] else {
                    return
                }
                completion(nil, nil, jsonObject)
            } catch {
                print("Error: Trying to convert JSON data to string")
                return
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

I call it like this

```
      APICaller.sharedInstance.performCallToEndpoint("/library/" + bookId, using: "GET", body: nil) { (error, serverError, response) -> () in
                
                if let response = response {
                    let value = response as! [String: Any]?
                    
                    if value?["id"] != nil {
                        self.removeFromLibrary = true;
                        self.libbtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "icon-bookmark-lg"), for: .normal)
                    } else {
                        self.removeFromLibrary = false;
                        self.libbtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "icon-bookmark-w"), for: .normal)
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is this line correct?

```
          if let response = response {
               let value = response as! [String: Any]?
```

I want to convert the response object into a Dictionary and access the values using specific keys.

Comment: you only need one line `if let value = response as? [String: Any] { }`

Answer (score 0):

You can change it here

```
try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] else
```

And here accordingly

```
@escaping......... _ response: [String:Any]?) -> Void) {
```

It's better also to use `Codable`  or [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)

> Note: According to  your response structure value here `as? <#Value#>` could be either `[String:Any]` or `[[String:Any]]` so cast to both and use what works the former is a dictionary while the latter is an  array of dictionaries